# Feature selection

Tags: r-caret, feature-selection, rfe

I am trying to find a useful feature selection method on a set of 20000 genes from an expression `set(microarray)` to get a model with the useful genes only.
I tried using RFE from caret but I got a stackOverflow since backward selection does not support data where `n(predictors) > n(samples)`.
Could anyone suggest a reasonable method to do so, or a solution for this RFE selection method?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

did you try using genetic algorithms for feature selection? There are different packages to do this - GA, genalg, caret (in R).

Take a look at this blog, feature selection using genetic algorithms has been explained with example - http://topepo.github.io/caret/GA.html

Hope it helps.